# Ayuda con paginador de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas noches a toda la comunidad, tengo el siguiente problema con el paginador de laravel, estoy haciendo una consulta por medio de un controlador a una base de datos en sql server, la consulta es la siguiente:

$data = VistaAHUMA00017::whereBetween('FechaDate', [$request->fecha_inicial, $request->fecha_final])
->whereBetween('HoraTime', [$request->hora_inicial, $request->hora_final])
->paginate(10);

esto me muestra mis registros correctamente paginados en la vista, el problema viene cuando paso a la segunda pagina, por algún motivo parece como si no tuviera datos, sin embargo si que tiene mas datos para paginar, adjunto una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no termino de comprender, es que cuando pongo datos fijos, sin pasar variables sobre la consulta, la paginacion funciona perfectamente, según lo que he alcanzado a detectar es que esta deja de funcionar al pasarle las variables para hacer la consulta, es como si al pasar al siguiente enlace las variables ya no sirvieran mas, esto solo me ha pasado con sql server, en mysql siempre me ha funcionado perfectamente...

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "poner datos fijos"?, ¿puedes mostrar cómo estás imprimiendo el paginador?

Answer (score 0):

La primera es que por lo que se puedo ver en el error es que estás tratando de acceder a una ruta por el método equivocado, falta que pongas en tu pregunta la ruta que estás ocupando y el HTML de la parte del paginador.

Recuerda que para cuando estás paginando usando filtros como las fechas y horas de tus datos deberías de estarlos mandando al paginador para que en cada página los tome en cuenta y no se pierdan, por ejemplo:

Si tu pones sólo esto `{{ $registros->links() }}` en tu vista para imprimir el paginador y tu URL es la siguiente: `www.abc.com?fecha_inicial=2018-09-05`, tu url quedaría solo como `www.abc.com?page=1,2,...` al momento de paginar y estaría ignorando los parámetros adicionales, la solución sería poner tu paginador de la siguiente forma:

```
{{ $registros->appends(['fecha_inicial' => $datos['fecha_inicial'], 'fecha_final' => $datos['fecha_final'], 'hora_inicial' => $datos['hora_inicial'], 'hora_final' => $datos['hora_final']])->links() }}
```

**(Aclaro que si no tienes esas variables definidas en la vista te daría error, ya tu tendrías que validar que existan con un operador ternario por ejemplo.)**

De esta forma aplicaría para una ruta usando el método `GET` y si lo estás haciendo con `POST` no lo recomendaría ya que en primera, el método `POST` no debería de estar regresando una vista, que al parecer, yo creo que estás mandando los filtros de un formulario por el método `POST` después estás devolviendo la vista con los datos filtrados y al momento de hacerle clic a algún link del paginador te arroja ese error ya que un enlace accede a una ruta usando el método `GET` y la tuya se encuentra en `POST`.